# Videos broken after cache.manifest

Tags: ios, caching, cache-manifest

So I am trying to get a web app to cache a few videos so they play offline. The web app will be only for iPad.

My HTML is 4 simple videos, a stylesheet and a debug.js file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="cache.manifest" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<script src="debug.js"></script>
<title>Mobile Cache Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <video width="640" height="480" controls="controls">
        <source src="slide1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video><br/>
    <video width="640" height="480" controls="controls">
        <source src="slide2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video><br/>
    <video width="640" height="480" controls="controls">
        <source src="slide3.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video><br/>
    <video width="640" height="480" controls="controls">
        <source src="slide4.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

I've added the directive to my .htaccess file `AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest`

My cache.manifest file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2012-06-13:v1
slide1.mp4
slide2.mp4
slide3.mp4
slide4.mp4
style.css
debug.js

NETWORK:
*
```

Now my issue is when I open it the first time I see 4 videos and they can all play. It also asks if I will allow the site to increase the data limit to 25MB. I say yes. Through my debug.js I can see the videos downloading. I can also see on my iPad if I go to `Settings > Safari > Advanced > Website Data` that the site is taking up 12.9MB.

So now I close safari and reopen and browse to the page. The 4 videos are now broken. They have the iPad play button with a slash through it and they won't play. Does anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: It looks like videos will not playback from the webapp cache. Check this related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899561/ios-web-app-video-caching-playback-issue-mp4

Comment: Yean, I never figured out this issue..bummer. Not sure if it is a bug or that is the way its supposed to work. I'd classify it as a bug, but that's just me. Apple does weird things